# Are all groups of order 6 cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For exactly the value of n=6, it is true that every group of order n is cyclic? I believe it is false, but cannot find the contradiction!

Comment: Check out $D_6$ dihedral group of 6 elements

Answer (score 7):

Up to isomorphism, there are *exactly two groups* of order $6$:

- the cyclic group of order $6$: $\mathbb Z_6$, or if you prefer, $C_6$,
- the non-abelian symmetric group $S_3$

Put differently, every group of order $6$ is isomorphic to exactly *one of two groups*:

- $\mathbb Z_6$
- $S_3$

For example, as pointed out in the comments, the dihedral group of order $6$ (the group of symmetries of the equilateral triangle) is isomorphic to $S_3$.

---

N.B. Knowing that there are exactly two groups, up to isomorphism, of order $6$ is a *good thing to know*, just as is the fact that there are exactly two groups, up to isomorphism, of order $4$: $\mathbb Z_4$: the cyclic group of order $4$, and the Klein 4-group, which is abelian, but not cyclic.

Comment: I've been waiting to upvote the person who pointed this out.

Comment: ;-) Thanks, @Douglas.  I couldn't resist posting this: it was screaming to be stated.

Answer (score 5):

$S_3$ is of order 6, and nonabelian.

Comment: $S_3$ is known as the symmetric group of order 3 - it can be thought as the set of permutations of the set {1,2,3}

Comment: ...and it is isomorphic to $D_6$, the dihedral group of order $6$.

Comment: assuming 1 is the identity

Comment: If you mean that 1 in the set {1,2,3} is the identity, then no - I should probably explain what I mean slightly better. A permutation of a set A is a bijection from A to A, so in the above case when considering the set {a,b,c} (relabelled for ease), the identity is the map from a to a, b to b and c to c. Under the operation of composition of functions when operating on the set of permutations, we then get the symmetric group.

Comment: This is also the group of symmetries of an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Every abelian group $G$ of order 6 is cyclic.

If $a$ is an element of order 2, $a^2=1$ and $b$ is an element of order 3 $b^3=1$ what is the order of the element $ab$?

The existence of elements $a$ and $b$ follows from the fact than for every prime divisor of the order of a group there exists an element of such order (Cauchy)

In general if  $G$ isn't abelian and has order $|G|=pq$,  $p,q$ primes then

$G=<a,b|b^p=1,a^q=1,a^{-1}ba=b^r>$ where $r\not\equiv 1 \mod p$ and $r^q\equiv 1 \mod p$ and $q|p-1$.

Comment: I thought Cauchy's theorem was for finite groups in general, not just Abelian groups?

Comment: Yes of course Cauchy's theorem applies in groups of finite order in general.

Comment: Interestingly, every group of order $6$ (or more generally, $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes) with non-trivial centre is cyclic.

Comment: Ah, I assume that is related to how $C_m \times C_n \cong C_{mn}$ if and only if m and n are coprime?

Comment: In addition if it's not abelian then $G=<a,b|b^p=1,a^q=1,a^{-1}ba=b^r>$ where $r\not\equiv 1 \mod p$ and $r^q\equiv 1 \mod p$ and $q|p-1$.

Comment: @AndrewD: I am assuming you comment was a reply to mine? Begin by showing that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. Then apply the result you quote.

Comment: @user1729 It was - although I can't see how the $G/Z(G)$ results helps.

Comment: @AndrewD: If $G$ has order $pq$ with non-trivial centre then the $G/Z(G)$ result means that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @user1729 Okay, so we have that: 1) As $G$ has non-trivial centre, we know that $Z(G)$ has order $p$,$q$ or $pq$; 2) Thus as $|G/Z(G)| = 1$,$p$ or $q$ we have that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic; 3) Therefore we have that G is Abelian; 4) By Lagrange, we know that we have subgroups $ C_p \cong H \triangleleft G$ and $C_q \cong K \triangleleft G$; 5) We can then easily show that $ H \cap K = e$ and $G=HK$, so $G = H \times K \cong C_p \times C_q \cong C_{pq}. I hope this is right.

Comment: Pretty much. You maybe want to say *why* $H$ and $K$ are normal (because $G$ is abelian). You probably also want to point out that $G/Z(G)$ cannot have order $p$ or $q$ in point $3$. But these are superficial things. Your proof is essentially complete.